# Android - how to pass context parameter to a method?

Tags: android, parameters, android-context

I'm trying to develop a simple app for my daughter but I'm not a professional :)

I was wondering how you can pass a context to a Boolean method?

My issue is, when trying to merge both codes below

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
     = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null;}
```

with

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
        urlc.connect();
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
    }
} else {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
}
return false;}
```

I am getting the error because I don't know how to pass a `Context` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
         = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

With this:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, having a reference to a Context is often needed in Android.

Basically, if you have a look at the [Context class doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), you'll see, that 2 very important classes are subclassed from it: Application and Activity (including all its variations like FragmentActivity, etc).

So the technique is straightforward: anywhere the Context is needed you do one of those

- Pass a Activity/Application object as a Context
- Use a Singleton pattern for keeping Context field (custom Application class is often used for it, see [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext()))

Concerning your piece of code:
The `getSystemService()` is actually a method of Context class, and I guess you call it somewhere inside of Activity object (as Activity is a Context subclass). So there is no reason to pass Context object in `... if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) ...`, just remove this argument until `isNetworkAvailable()` method is kept in Activity.

**Beware of keeping a strong reference to the context!**

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context ctx) {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
     = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null;}
```